# Replace word with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this text: `test **test** **test** **test**`

and I want to change `**test**` to `<b>test</b>` with this code:

```
var $text = 'test **test** **test** **test**';
$text = $text.replace(/\*\*[^\**]\*\*/,'<b>test</b>');
```

but i get this output: `test **test<b>test</b>test** **test**`

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fDM3h/)

**note**: between to stars can be anything. (like SO editor)

desired output: `test <b>test</b> <b>test</b> <b>test</b>`

what is the problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this works:

```
/\*\*[^\*]*\*\*/g
```

1. error: the quantifier star was within the character class
2. error: you need the global flag `g` to replace all occurences

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fDM3h/1/

code for replacing any content between **:

```
$text = $text.replace(/\*\*([^\*]*)\*\*/g,'<b>$1</b>');
```

Comment: especially with so many stars and slashes, its like being hit on the head ;)

Comment: Only problem with this is you don't actually *capture* the result, and so you'll have no means of returning the content in the replace callback.

Comment: @remus have you seen the second regex i wrote?

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
\*\*([^\*]+)\*\*
```

And replace with capture group `$1` like so: http://regex101.com/r/dJ7zG2

Also, you have no reason to use $ in javascript variables like that.

```
var text = "test **test** **test2** **somethingelse**";
text = text.replace(\*\*([^\*]+)\*\*, "<b>$1</b>");
```

Result:

```
"test <b>test</b> <b>test2</b> <b>somethingelse</b>"
```